# Phonegap/ngCordova iOS Facebook login for ionic unsuccessful

Tags: ios, facebook, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm implementing a native login to my ionic app. I'm able to switch from my app to facebook app when i press login, however when facebook app opens, it takes me back to my app's login page. It doesn't throw an error for some reason, here is my code (for brevity i just simplified the success and error):

```
 $cordovaFacebook.login(["user_friends"]).then(function(result){
      alert(result); //doesn't execute
        }, function(error) {
            alert(error); //doesn't execute
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is you are not getting call back from the facebook app .Function must be added in AppDelegate.m of your iOS build.Add the following code in AppDelegate.m

```
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
    return [[FBSession activeSession] handleOpenURL:url];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
    return [[FBSession activeSession] handleOpenURL:url];

}
```